# 19.10 newly installed but very slow operation on mid-2012 MacBook Pro 9.2

Tags: 19.10, macbook-pro, startup-applications

I installed Ubuntu 19.10 on a [MacBookPro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Third_generation_(Retina)) (9.2 mid-2012) with 16 GB RAM this week.

For about the first few days the system was running pretty fast but now it is taking about a minute to open a window such as the browser. I have looked here for solutions but nothing has worked so far. I re-installed that Ubuntu release after a complete erasure, twice, but the system is just as slow.

I just tried to boot Ubuntu and it just goes for a loop once I get into the login screen.

Would installing a different Ubuntu version (namely the LTS for Ubuntu 18.04) better solve this ?  Any help would be much appreciated.
Added:

```
officialmma2897798029@officialmma2897798029-MacBookPro:~$ lspci -v -s $(lspci| grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) 
Subsystem: Apple Inc. 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 2000 [size=64]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

This is the info for the free command

```
officialmma2897798029@officialmma2897798029-MacBookPro:~$ free

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       16302396     1279560    13724780      177536     1298056    14546460
Swap:       1003516           0     1003516
```

This is the info from df -h

```
officialmma2897798029@officialmma2897798029-MacBookPro:~$ df -h

Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                       7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      1.6G  1.8M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  456G  6.2G  426G   2% /
tmpfs                      7.8G   34M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                      7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1                  90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop2                  55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1223
/dev/loop3                  92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop5                  45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop4                 4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/501
/dev/loop6                  55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1668
/dev/loop0                 150M  150M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
/dev/loop7                  15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/317
/dev/loop8                 1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/sda2                  705M  193M  461M  30% /boot
/dev/sda1                  511M  7.8M  504M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                      1.6G   40K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb3                  5.2G   25M  4.9G   1% /media/officialmma2897798029/casper-rw
/dev/sdb1                  2.3G  2.3G     0 100% /media/officialmma2897798029/Ubuntu 19.10 amd64
```

I have just booted  the 64 bit version of lubuntu 18.0.4.4 LTS desktop amd64 (on a USB) and I think this should work. Would that be good enough for  making the system run at optimum speed?  The drive link is for the results from top command.

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/12mX2R8x5GUZnIOxoTbm6xsRPjbRPy1TC/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: You can open an Terminal-window and enter `top` to see how much CPU and memory processes draw. Also interesting might be remaining space on your personal folder.

Comment: During a period when it's slow, open a (slow) terminal, and look at the output of `df -h`, and `top`, and `free`. If you don;t understand the output, then copy-and-paste it into your question above (NOT comments below).

Comment: what are your specs, RAM and CPU?

Comment: Is the MacBookPro running hot? I believe this may be associated with the GPU in that MacBookPro. I have the same model, and the same thing happened to me. Trying 18.04 LTS which also uses the same GNOME Desktop Environment as 19.10 would not hurt, but I would instead try a lighter version, such as Ubuntu Budgie, Xubuntu, or Ubuntu MATE, all of which can be downloaded from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . The same install process as Ubuntu 19.10 works with those flavours, which are discussed further at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors and https://itsfoss.com/which-ubuntu-install/

Comment: Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Third_generation_(Retina) the GPU is _either_ Intel HD Graphics 4000 with DDR3 SDRAM shared w/ main RAM & _maybe also_ an NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M w/ 512MB-1GB GDDR5 RAM.. Let's find out which. Please open a terminal window and run _lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)_ then highlight and copy the result; return here, click [edit] & paste that into your question so we can see which you have. Please don't use Add Comment; that's our channel to you. Your channel to us is the (edited & updated) question.